# ASP.NET, 401 - Unauthorized, Valid account

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, authentication, config

This is a bit complicated

I'm running a .NET 4.0 site on a IIS 7.5, using Windows Authentication and running the site in custom application pool with Identity set to a Domain Admin account(need to run scripts with admin rights).

My webconfig is as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>

</system.web>
```

Whenever i log on to the site, using IE8 (it should authenticate me automaticly) it asks me for credentials, and I supply some generic Domain User credentials, I'm denied until it gives me the error: 
    401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

However, If I supply it my Domain Admin credentials, I'm granted access, good for me, but bad for my users :)

What is going on?

Some common problems people have are: Setting NTML as the default Authentication provider, no dice. And the wwwroot folder isn't shared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- After removing IIS role and creating
  it again.
- Setting up a new App Pool with the
  right credentials, and .NET 4.0
- Running this fix again
  http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/fix-bad-module-managedpipelinehandler-in-iis7
- Recreating my site under default
  website
- Converting it to an application
- Setting it up to use the right pool

The problem has solved itself

Answer (score 2):

Did you enable your Windows authentication in your IIS7.5 for site in your Virtual Directory?

[image]